# .NET Core App | IIS | HTTP Error 500 - Could not load configuration. Exception message: Attribute 'processPath' is required

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to host two applications in IIS in Windows Server 2019, in the same site. One of the applications is a website's front-end, in Angular, and the other one is the website's API, in ASP.NET MVC (.NET Core 2.2.8).
The front-end application's URL is `site_url/portal` and the API's is `site_url/api`.

Before using the API's other actions, one has to request a JSON web token from the `site_url/api/identity` URL, using Windows Authentication.
The front-end seems to be working fine, but trying to reach the `site_url/api/identity` API in the quality control environment yields "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error".
I activated detailed logs in IIS and the error message in Event Viewer was "Could not load configuration. Exception message: Attribute 'processPath' is required."
The API's web.config file does have a process path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PortalAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Aditionally, the IIS error page shows something which I find strange. The request URL is correct, but the physical path is `application_path\identity`. "Identity" is an MVC controller, not a file.

The .NET Core 2.2 Windows Hosting Bundle is installed and the .NET path environment variable is set.
The application pool identity is an applicational user, and .NET CLR version is set to "No Managed Code".
The site has both Anonymous Authentication (for the front-end login page) and Windows Authentication enabled.

The thing is, I have hosted the applications in the exact same way in both the development environment and a clean Azure virtual machine, and they work in both, which makes me think this has to do with some setting in either IIS or the quality control machine itself.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem and/or possible solutions might be?

Comment: I downloaded the asp.net core repository from Github, and had a look.  There's a single reference to "Attribute 'processPath' is required" in the repository; it's in a test harness that populates a dictionary with error messages.  Unfortunately the trail of bread crumbs ends there; I was unable to figure out where the dictionary is used, or where that particular error message is accessed.

Comment: try to se the   `app.UsePathBase("/DotNetCoreApp");` in your app. [link1](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6027) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194917/hosting-a-net-core-application-in-iis-could-not-load-configuration-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

A missing configuration caused this error for me until I added it: environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PortalAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" >
    <environmentVariables>
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
```

You can put this in **web.config**, but it will get removed if you publish a new version of the web app from Visual Studio. To avoid that, put it in **applicationHost.config** instead (in the location corresponding to your site).